# Call same Web Service multiple times from different View Controllers(not at the same time) in ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rest

I was just wondering what would be the best way to call the same Web Service from Different View Controllers(at different time). What architecture or design should I follow? I don't want to write the same code in each View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a network manager class, that takes the web service  parameters if any as arguments.

Here is a crude example of the architecture

```
class YourNetworkManager {



     public func callSpecificWebService(argument : Type?, [optional closure to handle results]) {

          // Generate the actual URL to be called here. Usually by 
          // appending a suffix to some constant base url 

          // The web service call mechanism goes here.
          // This could either use the NSURLSession API 
          // or some third party library such as Alamofire

          // Process the generic response conditions from the web service  
          // here. Pass on the specific parts to the calling method.
       }
    }
```

As I mentioned, this is a crude example. The more modularised you can make things, the better it will be.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using Alamofire library I can suggest to use

```
class NetworkManager {
static let shared = NetworkManager()

static let alamofireManager: SessionManager = {
    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(_TIMEOUT)
    sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForResource = TimeInterval(_TIMEOUT)
    return Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
}()

func performRequest(url: String,
                    method: HTTPMethod = .get,
                    parameters: [String: Any] = [String: Any](),
                    encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
                    contentType: String? = nil,
                    headers: HTTPHeaders = [String: String](),
                    success: @escaping(Data, Int) -> (),
                    failure: @escaping(CustomError) -> ()) {

        debugPrint("NetworkManager is calling endpoint: \(url)")
        NetworkManager.alamofireManager.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: headers).validate().response { response in
            guard let status = response.response?.statusCode, let data = response.data else {
                if let error = response.error {
                    debugPrint("Error when calling endpoint \(url)")
                    failure(.unknownError(message: error.localizedDescription))
                }
                return
            }
            debugPrint("HTTP Status received: \(status)")
            success(data, status)
       }
    } else {
        failure(.noNetworkConnection)
    }
}
```

Please feel free to modify `failure` handler with your custom error or whatever you like.
Of course then you need to serialise the response.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a base class for Alamofire request like that:**

```
import Alamofire

/// Struct for create AlamofireRequestModal
struct AlamofireRequestModal {
    /// Struct constant for Alamofire.HTTPMethod
    var method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod
    /// Struct constant for path
    var path: String
    /// Struct constant for parameters
    var parameters: [String: AnyObject]?
    /// Struct constant for encoding:ParameterEncoding
    var encoding: ParameterEncoding
    /// Struct constant for headers
    var headers: [String: String]?

    ///method to get init
    init() {
        method = .post
        path = ""
        parameters = nil
        encoding = JSONEncoding() as ParameterEncoding
    }
}

///BaseService to call the api's
class BaseService: NSObject {
    /// network variable for Reachability
    let network = Reachability.init(hostname: "https://www.google.com")

    /**
     This is method for call WebService into Alamofire

     - parameter alamoReq: this is AlamofireRequestModal type request
     - parameter success: success response
     - parameter failure: failer object
     */
    func callWebServiceAlamofire(_ alamoReq: AlamofireRequestModal, success:@escaping ((_ responseObject: AnyObject?) -> Void), failure:@escaping ((_ error: NSError?) -> Void)) {
        guard (network?.isReachable)! else {
            debugPrint("\n No Network Connection")
            return
        }

        let request = Alamofire.request(alamoReq.path, method: alamoReq.method, parameters: alamoReq.parameters, encoding: alamoReq.encoding, headers: alamoReq.headers)
        // Call response handler method of alamofire
        request.validate(statusCode: 200..<600).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
            let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
            if let allHeaderField = response.response {
                allHeaderField.setHeaders()
            }
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                if statusCode == 200 {
                    success(data as AnyObject)
                } else {
                    failure(NSError.init(domain: "www.wen.com", code: 101010, userInfo: ["message": "Something went wrong. Please trt again."]))
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                failure(error as NSError?)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

> Then create a service class according to use, like here I am creating Profile service class for login and registration and profile type all api's are added in this class so you can create multiple serice class according to use:

```
import Alamofire

///Profile service to call the profile api's
class ProfileService: BaseService {
    /**
     This is request to BaseService to get Login

     - parameter email: User email id
     - parameter password: User password to login
     - parameter success: success response
     - parameter failure: failure response
     */
    func doLogin(email: String, password: String, success: @escaping ((_ response: AnyObject?) -> Void), failure: @escaping ((_ error: NSError?) -> Void)) {
        var request = AlamofireRequestModal()
        request.path = "www.yourpath.com"
        request.parameters = ["email": email as AnyObject,
                              "password": password as AnyObject
                            ]
        callWebServiceAlamofire(request, success: success, failure: failure)
    }
}
```

**Now, You can call this doLogin method of Profile service from anywhere like Or you can create more layer like Model class and call this service from model class or You can call directly like this:**

```
ProfileService().doLogin(email: "Email", password: "Password", success: { (response) in
    // Code here for handle success response
}) { (error) in
    // Code here for handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never pass your `Views` and/or `ViewControllers` to you `NetworkManager` class.
Suppose you have a `NetworkManager` class like this.

```
open class NetworkHelper {

    class var sharedManager: NetworkHelper {
        struct Static{
            static let instance: NetworkHelper = NetworkHelper()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    func request(_ method: HTTPMethod, _ URLString: String, parameters: [String : AnyObject]? = [:], headers: [String : String]? = [:], completion:@escaping (Any?) -> Void, failure: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

        let URL = "BASE_PATH" + "URLString"
        Alamofire.request(URL, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    completion(response.result.value!)
                case .failure(let error):
                    failure(error)
                    guard error.localizedDescription == JSON_COULDNOT_SERIALISED else {
                        return
                    }

                }
        }
    }
}
```

Now create a `BaseViewController` which inherit from `UIViewController` and write your API call with necessary parameters. 
For example in an API call you only need `userID` as param all else is `static`.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    func makeThisApiCallWithUserID(userId: Int) {
        NetworkHelper.sharedManager.request(.get, "api/v1/yourApiAddress", parameters: ["userId":userId as AnyObject],headers: ["Authorization":"Bearer agshd81tebsf8724j"], completion: { (response) in

        }) { (error) in

        }
    }
}
```

No you should inherit those `ViewController` in which you want the same API call and you do not want to write the code again.

```
class FirstChildViewController: BaseViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.makeThisApiCallWithUserID(userId: 123)
    }
}
class SecondChildViewController: BaseViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.makeThisApiCallWithUserID(userId: 13)
    }
}
class ThirdChildViewController: BaseViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.makeThisApiCallWithUserID(userId: 3)
    }
}
```

See I haven't write API code in `FirstChildViewController`, `SecondChildViewController`, `ThirdChildViewController` but still they can make the same API call with different parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Do you use Alamofire?, if yes then I have good method for it, written in NetworkHelper Class.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

open class NetworkHelper {

class var sharedManager: NetworkHelper {
    struct Static{
        static let instance: NetworkHelper = NetworkHelper()
    }
    return Static.instance
}

func request(_ method: HTTPMethod
    , _ URLString: String
    , parameters: [String : AnyObject]? = [:]
    , headers: [String : String]? = [:]
    , onView: UIView?, vc: UIViewController, completion:@escaping (Any?) -> Void
    , failure: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

    let URL = BASE_PATH + URLString
    Alamofire.request(URL, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                completion(response.result.value!)
            case .failure(let error):
                failure(error)
                guard error.localizedDescription == JSON_COULDNOT_SERIALISED else {
                    return
                }

            }
    }
}
}
```